# How can I kill the application?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a problem: I can not kill the application, I have tried the `finish();` and `ActivityManager` etc. but they have not worked (application starts up again).

Comment: Why do you want to "kill" it? It's against Android usability patterns.

Comment: your question is not clear buddy exactly what are you trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not recommended in Android it's against Android usability patterns. The main thing is that you don't need to stop/kill/close your app trough a single line of code `System.exit(0)` as @parag suggested to you. Doing so is an indication you missed some important point in Android development. If for some bizarre reason you have to do it, you need to `finish()` all `Activities`, stop all `Services` and disable all `BroadcastReceivers` declared in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Android Activities lifecycles, the may give you a clue of how to achieve your needs. Anyway, you'll have to reconsider if your needs require to **KILL** the app. Its weird and its against Android recommendations.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Answer (score 0):

Use this one for Kill Apllication

```
System.exit(0)
```

Comment: You should never use `System.exit`. IIRC, it removes your process, and it can mess with the way Android handles Applications and Activities. Please don't use or ever recommend this.